# Cannot use Java BufferedReader to read from a file: Stream closed

Tags: java

I have to create a mini-interpreter in Java for a "Toy Language" and in this project, I have to include a FileTable which is a class having as private field a `HashMap<Integer, FileData>`, where FileData is:

```
public class FileData {
    private String fileName;
    private BufferedReader fileDescriptor;

    // methods...
}
```

Also, I have another class OpenRFile which has a method `execute(String fileName)`. This method creates a `BufferedReader` object for the given fileName and a `FileData` object which is added in the FileTable.

```
public class OpenRFile implements Statement {
    private String varName;
    private String fileName;

    // methods...
    public OpenRFile(String v, String f) {
        this.varName = v;
        this.fileName = f;
    }

    @Override
    public PrgState execute(PrgState p) {
        IDictionary<Integer, FileData> fileTable = p.getFileTable();
        IDictionary<String, Integer> symTable = p.getSymTable();

        if (symTable.contains(this.varName))
            throw new InterpreterException("Var name already exists.");

        for (Integer i: fileTable.getAll()) {
            if (fileTable.get(i).getFileName().equals(this.fileName))
                throw new InterpreterException("File is already open.");
        }

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.fileName))) {
            Integer id = IDGenerator.generateID();
            symTable.add(this.varName, id);
            fileTable.add(id, new FileData(this.fileName, br));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InterpreterException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OpenRFile(" + this.varName + ", " + this.fileName + ");";
    }
}
```

Later, in another class: `ReadFile`, the method `execute` just retrieves the `FileData` object from the `FileTable` and calls the method `readLine()` on the `BufferedReader` object, and this is the moment when I get the `Steam closed` error.

```
public class ReadFile implements Statement {
    private Expression exp;
    private String varName;

    // methods...
    public ReadFile(Expression e, String v) {
        this.exp = e;
        this.varName = v;
    }

    @Override
    public PrgState execute(PrgState p) {
        IDictionary<String, Integer> symTable = p.getSymTable();
        IDictionary<Integer, FileData> fileTable = p.getFileTable();

        Integer id = this.exp.eval(symTable);

        if (!fileTable.contains(id))
            throw new InterpreterException("File not found.");

        Integer read;

        try  {
            BufferedReader br = fileTable.get(id).getFileDescriptor();
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileTable.get(id).getFileName()));
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                read = 0;
            else
                read = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InterpreterException(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (symTable.contains(this.varName))
            symTable.update(this.varName, read);
        else
            symTable.add(this.varName, read);

        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReadFile(" + this.exp + ")";
    }
}
```

If I retrieve the fileName from the `FileData` object and create a new `BufferedReader` object, it works. But if I try to call `readLine()` directly on the object I already have, I get the error.

Comment: You're trying to read from a stream which you've closed elsewhere.  Without relevant code, we cannot help you further.

Comment: I don't call the `close()` method on the BufferedReader object. That's why I can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Add relevant code, BufferedReader can be closed automatically in many cases. Also you can add breakpoint to BufferedReader#close to debug what piece of code closed it.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: I added the code for both `OpenRFile` and `ReadFile` classes.

Comment: The try-with-resources block in `execute` will close the reader. You should store the path to the file, not the open stream.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created BufferedReader and FileReader in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. This means, that close() method was called on both directly after try block, as if there were `finally{fileReader.close();bufferedReader.close()}`.